# Does a pound on your foot equal 5 pounds on your back?

Tags: backpacking, footwear

I have heard a number of people say that a pound on your foot equals 5 pounds on your back. Is there any hard evidence to support this claim and how does the terrain affect it?

Comment: Consider skimming http://www.fjaderlatt.se/2009/11/weight-on-your-feet.html for additional reading on this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No,** this has not been shown in realistic mountain hiking settings.  It has only been shown for fast hiking.

The [answer by Tullochgorum](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/10894/566) links a 1984 US army study.  It is [quoted here](http://www.fjaderlatt.se/2009/11/weight-on-your-feet.html) (emphasis mine):

> The men walked **on a treadmill** with three different speeds; 4, 5.6 and 7.3 kilometers/hours.

(...)

> The energy cost of wearing boots was significantly higher at all speeds **except the lowest (4 km/h)**.

I don't think hiking at 6–7 km/h on a treadmill is a good model for how I hike.
Most people hike at closer to 4 km/h than to 6 km/h, in particular if they are on long treks with heavy backpacks in mountains or where trails are unmaintained or absent.  At such a speeds,  there is no evidence that "one pound on your foot equals 5 pounds on your back".

In other discussions, people mention hikers who have hiked tens of thousands of km.  I'm not convinced that what applies for ultra-long-distance hikers is necessarily good for those of us who have at most 4 weeks per year for hiking.  I suspect the ultra-long-distance hikers hike faster.

But regardless of whether you believe it's heavier, hike with whatever you consider safe and comfortable.  If trail shoes work for you, wear trail shoes.  If you find that you prefer strong ankle support (perhaps for those steep descends) and high height for swamp and stream crossings, wear "traditional" higher hiking boots.  My impression is that the lightweight shoes are more popular in N-America whereas larger hiking boots are more popular in The Alps or Scandinavia (incidentally, I've found trails steeper in the latter case as well; perhaps there is a link?).  In any case, both are available at good outdoor stores so having a "war" between the two camps is useless — nobody is forcing their preference upon others.  Or you can even decide to bring both :)

Comment: The study also included weighted sneakers and found that when matched for weight walking/running in sneakers required less energy. This is another argument for light trail runners, but also another strike against the 5x claim. It might even be that there is no difference even at speeds near 5.6 if you compare footwear with similar stiffness.

Comment: @StrongBad That passage says `48-70% of the difference was due to the weight` so I don't think the 5x rule is in such danger.

Comment: @GabrielC. if we adjust for the 48-70%, that means the saying should be a pound on the foot is 2.5-3.5 pounds on the back. The issue for me is that at realistic hiking speeds there is no reliable difference and even at faster speeds where there is a reliable difference, some of that difference is not due to the weight.

Answer (score 14):

The factor of 5 maybe an exaggeration, but the physics is certainly worth examining.

Consider what is happening as you walk.

### Backpack

Take easy ground to begin with - your pack moves at a fairly constant speed and velocity - essentially the only energy needed from you is holding the weight in the air. On rough ground, experienced backpackers will keep this motion of the backpack (and their torso) smooth and consistent. Even on very rough ground it's surprising how little a backpack moves with little bobbing up and down and starting and stopping. The smoother the pack is moving, the less energy is used changing its velocity. (Novices often have very inefficient carrying technique, stopping and staring each step, bobbing up and down like a yoyo, especially on rough ground.)

### Feet

The very nature of your feet is your boots/shoes stop and accelerate to twice your walking speed each step. They also have to be lifted and placed down on the ground. None of the energy from one step is retained for the next. Any extra weight on your feet needs to follow the same actions, hence it's very inefficient. The only benefit is half the time the weight of boots is supported by the ground, not you.

On easy ground, the difference is more significant as the backpack motion is hardly changing. Over rough ground, as the backpack needs to accelerate slow down more, and bob up and down (e.g. boulder hopping, climbing over trees etc), the penalty of weight on feet diminishes significantly.

Edit: 
One thing that must be considered is the nature of the ground and support you need for your feet. At one extreme, a few people can carry heavy weights over very rough ground easily in bare feet. At the other, as I drive a desk for 50 weeks a year, my feet are not strong enough to carry heavy weight over rough ground without support. Therefore although lighter weight shoes/boots are less tiring, the support and protection provided by the shoe becomes more important than weight. It's one thing to walk a few hours in Crocs along a benched track, another to spend 14 days crossing mountain passes and river beds with no formed tracks carrying 20kg back pack.

Comment: With  training, I would go hiking in water boots.  Essentially a neoprene sock with a rubber sole.  Got started on this canoeing.  At 50 I was still running circles around the 14-17 year old boys on our 1 week trip.

Comment: My own feeling is that the factor of 5 is actually an under-estimate. The studies I've seen would average over 5, and they mostly use treadmills. In real life there is often a lot of high-stepping up rocks, over windfall etc that would  surely add significantly to the energy cost. What you don't really point out is that the boot weight is on the end of the longest levers on the body, while a good pack is close to the centre of gravity. Also, the relative weight of the boots and pack is just for illustration - the take-home point is that heavy boots are very tiring, especially on rough ground.

Answer (score 8):

Yes - it's true.

The source is a 1984 study by the U.S. Army Research Institute, which found that it takes up to 6.4 times as much energy to move at a given pace when weight is carried in the footwear as against the torso.

When I was a kid we all walked in monsters like this, at almost 4 lbs a pair (and that's **before** they get wet!):

[image]

This is the equivalent of around 20 lbs in your pack. I still see a lot of people shod like this, particularly continentals in the Western Alps.

Now (unless it's icy) I walk the hills in minimalist shoes like these, at around 1lb per pair. This is the equivalent of dropping over 15lbs from my pack.

[image]

It's been a total liberation. My feet, knees and hips function as they evolved to function, and I'm experiencing far less fatigue, wear and tear. And I've never had so much as a hot-spot, never mind a blister.

Heavy boots are supposed to provide ankle protection, but because they don't allow your power train to function properly I used to experience regular injuries - sometimes quite serious. Walking thousands of miles in more natural shoes, I've never had a problem.

And being able to actually feel the ground beneath your feed adds a great deal of enjoyment to walking, at least for me. I wouldn't want to isolate myself from the ground again any more than I'd want to wear chain-mail to make love.

Of course wearing light footwear does involve some commitment and a change of attitude. You have to transition carefully and rebuild the natural strength in your feet. You have to step lightly and accurately on difficult ground. You have to lighten your pack. You have to pick the right shoes for the job, or adapt them to the terrain with removable rock-plates. It's all part of a more lightweight approach to moving and living in the mountains.

For me there's no turning back. I've walked long distances over tough terrain, and as I've built my strength and skills it's become an integral part of my enjoyment of the hills.

Comment: I grew up backpacking/hiking all over the cascades using cross trainers. In the military I used boots and regularly pined for my cross trainers. In contrast my wife has noticeably more stability and confidence when she wears "proper" hiking boots.

Comment: The vast majority of this answer is irrelevant to the question, would love to see the details for the study expanded and your personal views condensed.

Comment: Just spotted a study at London University that came up with a similar result:

Comment: Continued...

Just spotted a study at London University that came up with a similar result:

http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00140138608968276

There are other papers replicating these results. You'll find a very  extensive technical discussion here:

http://www.fjaderlatt.se/2009/11/weight-on-your-feet.html

Comment: You mention that people use the "heavy" boot (how much does that boot weigh? You can't tell just by looking at it) with the implication that it's unwise, but you don't mention what terrain, pack weight or weather that boot is being taken into.

Comment: @NathanPaulSimons Not clear what you're downvoting here - I mentioned that the heavy pair of boots weighs about 4lbs, that I use the lightweight shoes for all hillwalking other than snow and ice, and that they need to be adapted to the terrain. I personally prefer them in all terrains and pack weights outside of winter conditions. A full discussion of footwear would be off-topic - my aim was simply to alert people to the option of discarding heavy, tiring and over-engineered boots. Based on the research, going back to my old boots would effectively double my base-weight while alpine trekking.

Comment: @NathanPaulSimons - still not following you - I don't impugn anyone's choice - simply share my own experience. It seems to me that alerting people to choices they might not be aware of is a perfectly reasonable thing to do?

Comment: *I wouldn't want to isolate myself from the ground again*, by that reasoning you might as well walk barefeet, and indeed, some people do.

Comment: @gerrit I do go barefoot at times when it's practical. But much more often the need for traction and protection from rocks, thorns, ticks etc means that some kind of footwear is sensible. So nowadays I choose the lightest footwear that ix fit for task. My point here is that the old dogma that you have to lug around 3-4 lbs of leather and steel on the end of your longest levers to move safely in the hills has been disproven by a large community of lightweight walkers who are enjoying the multiple benefits of more minimal footwear. So you have a wider range of options to choose from.

Comment: @Tullochgorum Let's agree on the final point: a wider range of options (a good thing).  Trail shoes may be suitable for trails, and some may choose to wear them on rougher terrain.  I haven't seen them in rougher areas of Scandinavia like Sarek.  I wonder if people wear them on trailless wilderness routes in areas like [Kluane/Wrangell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kluane_/_Wrangell%E2%80%93St._Elias_/_Glacier_Bay_/_Tatshenshini-Alsek), [Tweedsmuir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_MacKenzie_Heritage_Trail), or in the [Brooks Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks_Range)...

Comment: @gerrit Provided you're fully transitioned light trail shoes work just fine in the kind of country you've mentioned. People like Andrew Skurka, Chris Townsend and Cam Honan regularly do fearsome off-trail walks all over Alaska, Canada, Scandinavia, the Sierra and beyond, along with many less well-known walkers. I've done all sorts of off-piste stuff myself in the UK and the Alps, and as I've said I feel safer and more stable. For Sarek I'd take my barefoot shoes without a second thought. You're going to get wet there whatever you wear, so why not take something that drains and dries?

Comment: @Tullochgorum Perhaps I should try, although even the Vivobarefoot brand you mention has everything from [this](http://www.vivobarefoot.com/uk/mens/motus-mens)or [this](http://www.vivobarefoot.com/uk/mens/stealth-lux-mens?colour=Black/Gold) to [this “lightweight heavyweight”](http://www.vivobarefoot.com/uk/mens/tracker-mens).  I've never had injuries in my high boots but I concede it's a pain when they get wet.  A closer look at the 1984 study says *The energy cost of wearing boots was significantly higher at all speeds except the lowest (4 km/h).*.

Comment: @Tullochgorum When I'm navigating swamps, boulder fields, or bushwhacking, my speed is (quite a bit) less than 4 km/h, which again suggests that what may be true on a trail might not apply in rough wilderness country.  Based on my own experience, I certainly agree that *running* in boots is a pain (except on a good trail descending).  So I'd like to see some evidence where the same experiment is performed not on a flat treadmill at 4–8 km/h, but in (a realistic simulation of) trailless backcountry in terrain like the mountains of Scandinavia or Alaska where 2–4 km/h is more realistic.

Comment: @Tullochgorum *why not take something that drains and dries* — because my feet hurt when I try in lightweight shoes and my feet don't hurt when I try in traditional boots.  Perhaps my feet will stop hurting after several weeks of Sarek hiking.  Perhaps not.  I'm not going to try because apart from testimonies of some people who apparently have a lot more spare time than I do, I haven't seen evidence (the treadmill experiment is inapplicable, as I've pointed out above).

Answer (score 5):

Regarding energy expense, there is already a good answer.  However, I want to add that when considering "Does a pound on your foot equal 5 pounds on your back?" there are more factors at play than just energy expense.  You should also consider the effect on knees and joints.  As an example - If I put 5 lb weights on both my feet and went up and down stairs for a while... though tired, my knees would be fine.  However if I put 50 lbs. on my back and did that, my knees would *not* be okay (I have done this test). Weight on your feet does not impact your knees the same way as weight on your back.

When it comes to wear and tear on the joints and ligaments that support your body, a simple rule like this is not sufficient.

Comment: This is really excellent. Generally, at least for me, my knees and back ache at the end of the day more so than my muscles being tired.

Answer (score 4):

This saying appears to be mostly common sense or "homespun" wisdom, but there are some studies that have tried to dig into it:

This [HowStuffWorks Adventure article](http://adventure.howstuffworks.com/outdoor-activities/hiking/one-pound-off-feet-five-pounds-off-back.htm) mentions Hillary's ascent of Everest, as well as the Army study mentioned in another answer here. The general consensus is that yes, mass on the feet incurs more cost in energy to move than mass on the back (between 4.7 and 6.4 times as much).

Keep in mind that while it may be true that weight on the foot will take more energy to move than some multiple of weight on the back, there are more factors to consider:

1) First and foremost is ankle support and foot protection. If you are overweight, your pack is heavy, or the terrain you are travelling on is very rough, you may want more support and protection for your feet and ankles. This naturally leads to wearing heavier footwear. Your level of training, both in technique and in strength of your ankles and feet, will make a difference in how light of footwear you can get away with.

2) The three heaviest items for backpacking *don't* include footwear. Look first to reducing the weight of your pack, shelter and sleeping bag plus pad. Even shaving off a pound in footwear won't get you anywhere near the savings of going lighter in the big three. And doing this first may allow you to go with lighter footwear as well.

3) Your bodyweight may also be a factor, and not just for what footwear you choose. I wasn't even very heavy, but dropping 35lbs of fat was the equivalent of halving my week long backpack weight! And it pays off every day on being easier on my joints *and* I'm in much better health overall. Plus, being at a lighter weight and having strengthened my ankles and honed my hiking technique, I can choose lighter footwear.

Footwear manufacturers are trying all the time to reduce weight, so just looking at a big bulky boot and saying there is no place for it is unwise; how do you even know how much it weighs? How are you looking to put the footwear to use? Even many safety boots these days are being fitted with carbon fiber instead of steel for toe protection and shanks (which can be useful on certain mountainous terrain).

I personally try to go as light as I can to the point of using approach shoes or trail runners for 20+ mile day hikes. I've seen guys do highly technical rugged day hikes in Five Fingers (the old ones, not the newer thicker ones) and other guys hike week long back pack trips in Tevas. That being said I still keep my heavy high top boots for things like snowshoeing, and for serious winter mountaineering, I have double-walled plastic boots. Having a shank and steel toe is not necessarily a bad thing; in particular, stiffer soled boots will edge better. See ["Freedom of the Hills" section on boots](https://books.google.com/books?id=GwyXx4DzDjwC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22Freedom+of+the+Hills%22+boot+shank&source=bl&ots=lDvveGjR5y&sig=JqrmgiEW6jHDI4TQYyf2xElE2Ag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRleOFoKrMAhWCHB4KHdmLCnkQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Freedom%20of%20the%20Hills%22%20boot%20shank&f=false) for more details.

Comment: While all good advice, this does not answer my question. I was specifically asking about evidence supporting the 5lb claim.

Comment: At the suggested five-to-one ratio, switching from my heavy hiking boots (3.5 pounds) to my trail shoes (1.5 pounds) is equivalent to leaving my pack, tent, sleeping bag, and foam pad (10 pounds total) at home.

Comment: @Mark - Sounds like you definitely need to slim down your big three then, and doing that will make it that much easier on your feet and safer to go with lighter footwear. Or possibly you need better boots. Bigger boots with more protection don't have to weigh that much.