# Why do so many people hike with such light footwear?

Tags: footwear

More and more, I see people hiking with very light-weight shoes.  To me, they look like regular sport shoes and they look to be lacking thick soles, waterproofness, or ankle support.  I thought this was a US phenomenon, but I saw that in two UK outdoor stores I visited, most shoes sold are such.  For example, a recent trip to Southern Utah, I partly hiked on popular trails in Zion National Park, such as the trail to Scout Lookout/Angels Landing and the trail to Observation Point.  Both trails include serious slopes where classical hiking boots (see picture below) would appear essential to me, yet I saw hundreds of people who hiked in lightweight shoes that looked unsuitable to me.  I observed the same in Bryce Canyon National Park, where a park newspaper lists improper footwear in a top-10 of injury causes as cause #3, #2 and #1. I did not notice this phenomenon on more remote trails or in other countries such as Norway, Sweden, Spain, Switzerland, where outdoor stores sell hiking boots rather than city shoes.

Why do so many people hike in serious mountains with light-weight footwear?  Is it an active choice?  I've tried sport shoesonce or twice for a short distance, and it was painful — I can't understand that someone would hike anything that isn't flat tarmac in such shoes.  They wouldn't keep my feet dry beyond the first stream crossing, either.

By a proper hiking boot, I mean something like this:

[image: hiking boot]

By lightweight sport shoes, I mean something like this:

[image: light sport shoe]

In Scandinavia, many people I meet hike in even higher boots, arguing they are more suitable to keep the feet dry.  I imagine that to be true, but I've never tried hiking in them and I don't think I've seen people using them outside Scandinavia:

[image: Swedish boot]

Do people actively choose hiking in lighter shoes (perhaps part of the American *ultralight* fashion?), or is it simply a matter of unpreparedness?

(See also: *[What is the point of hiking boots, versus any comfortable walking shoes?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5695/566)*)

Comment: Two answers from the question you linked pretty much answer your question:
http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/5698/3602 and http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/5700/3602

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38904/discussion-on-question-by-gerrit-why-do-so-many-people-hike-with-such-light-foot).

Comment: In Scandinavia, we also prefer the higher boots because of the decreased chance of snake bites. There are not many different kinds of snakes here (I think just one or two species that could be lethal for humans), so it is very effective prevention. Anyway, the principal reason is for keeping our foot dry as you suggest.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Hmm - more of a tirade than a question, but let's assume you sincerely want to learn. There's a good deal of ground to cover, so please bear with me here...

**First, technical trail shoes are not "city shoes"**

If we're going to have an intelligent conversation we need to clear this up from the outset. You describe all types of lightweight footwear as "city shoes". This is an unhelpful caricature. While street shoes are obviously inappropriate for tough walking, technical trail and approach shoes are designed specifically to provide the grip and robustness required for this type of terrain.

**Second - lightweight walkers are not simply unprepared fashion victims**

We have to put this in proper context. You imply that anyone using lightweight footwear on difficult ground is simply unprepared or following a mindless trend. In fact, you'll find that the more experienced the walker, the more likely that they will be choosing to use lightweight footwear.

I've been walking the hills for half a century. I've used every kind of footwear, and in almost all conditions I now have a strong preference for trail shoes. And I'm far from alone. Pretty much every experienced through-hiker is now using lightweight footwear, even on quite technical off-trail work like the Sierra High Route. In fact, I challenge you to find a single well-known long-distance walker using the kind of boot you are advocating.

So there are two possibilities. Either the entire community of long-distance walkers is experiencing some kind of collective delusion, or they know something that you are missing...

**Third - the traditional case for heavy walking boots doesn't stand up to scrutiny**

The specific claims you make for heavy footwear are that it protects the ankles and keeps the feet dry.

But where is your evidence that heavy boots protect the ankles? I can't find any actual research that's remotely convincing. To provide meaningful ankle support, a boot has to be so rigid that it's virtually impossible to walk in the thing. In reality, a walking boot, as against a technical ice boot, provides insignificant ankle support when laced for comfort. On the other hand the high stack height, stiff sole and poor ground feel disrupt natural walking mechanics and leave you clumsy and unstable. I experienced a number of serious ankle injuries in conventional boots. Since I switched to lightweight trail shoes I've never had a problem, and I do a lot of rough off-trail walking.

As for the idea that big boots keep the feet dry, I don't know many real walkers who'd agree. Your feet sweat, and heavy boots don't breathe. But the membranes in so-called breathable waterproof boots quickly break down and leak. And with any practical summer gaiter, water is going to penetrate through the gap at the ankle. Once they are wet, the type of boot you are advocating becomes even heavier and takes an age to dry.

The great majority of long-distance walkers simply accept that their feet will get wet at times. They chose shoes that drain well and dry quickly, and wear merino socks that are warm when wet. On balance, this is much the most successful approach.

**Most long-distance walkers agree that the benefits of lightweight footwear greatly outweigh the disadvantages**

The real disadvantage of lightweight trail shoes is economic - you're going to be replacing them after every 500 miles or so of heavy use. On every other dimension, they are a much better choice than the old leather monsters that you are advocating.

1. **Trail shoes are far more energy efficient**: research shows that a pound on the feet is equivalent to at least 5 lbs on the back. And on steep rough ground, that's probably an underestimate (the research was done on treadmills). Lightweight shoes are far less tiring to walk in, and you'll be significantly less prone to lower-body strain injuries.
2. **Trail shoes are far kinder on the feet**: I've walked thousands of miles in trail shoes and never had a hot spot, never mind a blister. When I walked in big boots I had endless problems with blisters and bruising. Search Google Images for "hiking blisters" and you'll see *graphic evidence of the misery big boots can cause:*

> [image: blistered bleeding feet]

3. **Trail shoes are far more nimble**: you'll be significantly more balanced and less liable to fall. Falls in remote country can be serious, so this is a big deal.
4. **Trail shoes are far better for stream crossings**. Stream crossings with big boots are a major faff. With trails shoes you just walk straight across. Your feet are grippy and protected during the crossing, and the shoes soon drain on the trail.

As I say, the more experienced the walker, the more likely that they will chose lightweight shoes. And this will be a considered choice based on many thousands of miles of practical experience. You're welcome to choose the footwear you prefer - that's the freedom of the hills. But please keep an open mind and don't denigrate those who make other choices.

Comment: Blisters aren't caused by boots, but by ill-fitting footwear. I've never had blisters from hiking boots but have from approach shoes - probably because they don't feel like they need any wearing in so it's easy to get it wrong the first time.

Comment: I don't know think I quite agree with you.  In places like Sarek Nationalpark, I haven't seen people hiking on light-weight shoes.  Could you link an example of such a *trail shoe*?  Are they for sale in regular stores, or must one go to "cottage manufacturers" such as for a lot of quality ultralight gear?  To me, the footwear I saw people use in Zion National Park seemed no different from regular sport shoes, that I tried to use for hiking exactly once on a painful day hike on [Churfirsten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churfirsten) (just one, not all seven).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what a trail shoe is.  [I have asked](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/11619/566).  Regardless of my confusion and disagreement (I frequently cross streams that are wide and shallow enough for high boots to be tremendously helpful), your post does answer my question.  I don't think I've ever tried technical trail shoes.

Comment: @gerrit A "Trail shoe" is something like this: http://www.merrell.com/UK/en_GB/mens-walking-shoes/ . They're explicity designed for hiking, share the same soles as actuall boots, etc.

Comment: As for the stream crossings, I fail to see how you would cross a 15 cm deep stream on 10 cm high shoes, when I can just walk through on my 20 cm high shoes without getting my feet wet.  Same for walking through swamps.  Whereas I can possibly see some of the other points you mention, the stream crossings one doesn't make any sense to me unless you can jump very far.  How do you keep your feet dry?

Comment: @ChrisH -  you're right - some people don't have problems with blisters in heavy boots. But I could never find a pair that were comfortable - and I tried on many, many different pairs over decades. I think this is quite a common issue. Being much lighter and more flexible, it's much easier to find a pair of trail shoes that fits.

Comment: @gerrit there is a wide choice of trail shoes from a wide range of specialist manufacturers (like VivoBarefoot) and mainstream brands like Merrell or Saucony. The can range from ultralight and minimal to quite heavy and stiff, and many different levels of cushioning and protection. Most long distance walkers prefer the lighter models designed for trail running. In mud you can use a fell running shoe. There are also approach shoes which are designed for walking and scrambling. In the US and the UK lightweight  trail shoes are becoming the norm, and there is no shortage of options.

Comment: Although I agree with some of your post and you are correct the OP was on a bit of a tirade I have to disagree with one large fundamental point you have made - do higher ankle boots provide ankle protection?  Simply, of course they do.  Ask any military organisation in the world.  The evidence is so overwhelmingly obvious that it's absurd to claim no evidence can be found.  Also, as someone who has broken both ankles whilst in "trail wear" I now rely solely on ankle length hiking boots to protect me and they have done just that on numerous occasions now that my proprioreceptors are damaged.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8584850 : "These studies support the use of high top shoes for ankle sprain prevention because of their ability to limit extreme ranges of motion, provide additional proprioceptive input and decrease external joint stress."   << They basically say boots don't stop sprains, but they stop being a whole lot worse.

Comment: As for streams, I don't seem to encounter many compliant 15 cm crossings! Getting big boots soaked is horrible, so for any serious crossing you have to 1) Take off your boots and socks 2) Put on something to protect your feet from rocks or risk getting cut or bruised 3) Have something handy to dry your feet 4) Pull your socks back onto damp feet. 5) Put on your boots and lace them up. I've done it hundreds of times and it's a major faff. By contrast, in a fast-draining trail shoe you simply keep walking, It's far more convenient and a big time-saver on days with many crossings.

Comment: @Venture2099 despite agreeing with you, my worst ankle injury (a minor sprain) was in boots not shoes.  Not my toughest boots admittedly.  Your second comment backs up my view that it would have been worse without the ankle support.

Comment: @Venture2099 Sorry to hear about your injuries. The first point I would make is that not all trail shoes are the same - I go for low stack shoes with high proprioception, and find that they allow my "power train" to recover naturally when my ankle starts to turn. Other designs don't offer this advantage. I have an ankle I ripped as a kid and had frequent re-injuries in boots. No injuries in 1000s of miles of walking in trail shoes. I feel much more confident, balanced and stable.

Comment: @Venture2099 As for the research, pubmed is down but here's an informed discussion on  SectionHiker: http://sectionhiker.com/myth-or-fact-do-hiking-boots-prevent-sprained-ankles/ Of course a high, stiff lace-up boot will offer protection, but my point is the kind of boot that people actually walk in  (particularly fabric boots) don't offer much protection. And I don't think that this has been researched. The more the protection, the harder they are to walk in, almost by definition. I've read dozens of accounts of through-hikes in lightweight shoes and never seen an issue with turned ankles.

Comment: @Venture2099 For people with specific ankle issues, I think there is quite decent evidence that a well-designed athletic support combined with a low stack trail shoe will be at least as effective as a stiff and heavy boot.

Comment: @Venture2099 I think the real danger with lightweight footwear is crush injuries - either from rocks in talus, or from slipping into, say, a V shaped gap between branches while crossing windfall. I do know of one well known walker who hurt himself this way and had to bail. So some care and attention is required. The ankle thing is a non-issue, I believe.

Comment: @Venture2099 OK - pubmed is back up. The abstract you link to actually states "clinical trials are inconclusive as to the clinical benefit of high top shoes in the prevention of ankle sprains". I don't think the research is as conclusive as you are claiming. In particular, the idea that heavy boots offer more proprioception than lightweight shoes seems perverse. The sole of the foot has the highest concentration of nerve-endings in the body - so they must have an important role in balance. Thick-soled boots isolate these important nerves from ground feel, throwing off the whole power train.

Comment: Trail shoes are great, and I use them. I also use "traditional" boots with heavier packs. Anyway, that's not as important as what happens when you absolutely mash your inner ankle bone on a piece of talus. I promise you will wish that 1/8" of leather was there when it happens. I think there are extremes in either case, so it's not an all-or-nothing deal. I was convinced to try trail shoes, and I love them now. However, there is certain terrain where I prefer something much sturdier.

Comment: @Tullochgorum OK, here's an account. In 2008 I did a section of the AT in trail runners. On top of one of many endless mountains I slipped on a wet rock next to a fire tower and twisted my ankle. It was still a painful few miles from there to the NOC, where I remained for six days. My problem, though, turned out not to be the shoes, but the fact that I wasn't using poles. After the _second_ incident near Fontana, (where I was laid up for two weeks) I wised up and bought a pair of overpriced poles there. I had no further issues, and even was able to move faster. I still use those very poles.

Comment: @MichaelHampton As you say, there's no reason why trail shoes should be any slippier than boots. My current shoes have Vibram soles, and they know a thing or two about formulating rubber. If anything, well-designed trail shoes should be better. Because of their shorter design life, it should be possible to use a softer, stickier compound.

Comment: @Tullochgorum you clealry didn't read what I wrote and are cherry picking.  I said (verbatim) "They basically say boots don't stop sprains, but they stop being a whole lot worse.."  You then counter with a post saying - "clinical trials are inconclusive as to...prevention."  Thanks for repeating my own statements back to me.   I also think it's absurd to claim that "thick soled" boots ruin proprioreceptor ability but somehow trail shoes don't.  At the end of the day a sole is a sole; it's a barrier and the difference between boot soles and trail shoe soles is negligible.

Comment: Also here is a great report into the use of Vibram soles which lead to greater level of injuries and significantly more pain across the lower leg.  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24357642  - it shouldn't really take a clinical investigation to understand that trying to simulate bare foot techniques are inferior to well designed outer wear.  A similar study of "bare skin versus parka jackets in cold weather" would be laughed at but because there is a fascination with (erroneously reported) indigenous African running ability we entertain this nonsense.

Comment: @Venture2099  It's the study you quote that's absurd - runners were required to use minimalist shoes without proper transitioning, so of course they got injured. But in this context the debate around running is irrelevant - injury rates are very high whatever the footwear. Walking is very different and there has been no research on minimal footwear. You seem to believe that we need to armour our feet as evolution didn't fit us for walking.  Almost everyone who walks long distances disagrees. What qualifies you to claim that experts like Andrew Skurka and Chris Townsend are promoting nonsense?

Comment: @Venture2099 The point you make about proprioception is heroically untrue. The shoes I have on my feet as I write offer literally orders of magnitude greater ground feel than a traditional leather boot. Have you ever worn a pair of lightweight trail shoes?   I think you're  writing from preconceptions rather than experience.

Comment: @Venture2099 As for the clinical trials, for sure they aren't comparing a high-ankle leather boot with a lightweight, low-stack, high ground-feel trail shoe. So the clinical evidence is moot. My experience, and the experience of thousands of other walkers is that frequency and severity of ankle sprains is reduced in the lightweight shoe, because the foot, ankle, knee and hip are able to do the job they evolved to do and protect the system from strain. You've described my views as "laughable",  "absurd" and "nonsense" but it's you that's out of step with the practical experience of the experts.

Comment: Define "experts".  I have driven 250,000 miles in car if not more yet I am not an expert in combustion engines, gearboxes or mechanical engineering.  Walking 1000's of miles in the hills no more qualifies you as a biomechanical expert than my mum walking to the shops her entire life.   You have your viewpoint (largely unsupported and anecdotal) and I have mine.  Let's depart as I simply don't believe your trail shoes have "orders of magnitude" greater ground feel (whatever the hell that actually is).

Comment: @Venture2099 Well, it seems that you trust marginally significant and barely relevant lab results more than the real life experience of thousands of people walking real trails. If you don't believe that a minimal trail shoe has very much more ground feel that a heavy boot with a steel or leather shank it's clear that you're arguing from a rather serious misconception of what's being proposed here. Perhaps you could actually try a pair on? So yes, let's agree to disagree, as we have no common ground to work from.

Comment: I actually trust the real life experience of millions of military combatants working across all imaginable terrain types.  All of whom wear high-top ankle boots of a leather nature.    So I see your amateur walkers and I trump you every modern army, ever.

Comment: @Venture2099: It is possibly not a good idea to take the military as the last word in effective equipment.  Consider that as recently as a few decades ago, the US military was still teaching the sort of close-order drill that is really effective in resisting calvary charges.  And starching/blocking hats (excuse me, 'covers'), blousing trousers, etc :-(

Comment: @jamesqf - You're right to be sceptical of the military as a model of good equipment. In the Falklands the UK army boot had serious problems: http://goo.gl/DuQWCw. Outdoor shops were swamped with squaddies buying boots before deployment. The UK boot is still hopeless: http://goo.gl/ttLFaa. The Australian boot is a "horror story": http://goo.gl/JRYgSt. The US allow squaddies to choose boots from a wide range of suppliers, but their current packframe breaks in combat and doesn't allow a proper shooting position when prone. US Marine equipment in Iraq was still a screwup: http://goo.gl/u79r3T

Comment: *There's a good deal of ground to cover....*

Comment: Comments about the effectivness of individual items of military equipment are a complete red herring as any peice of equipment is the sum of numerous budgetary and political decisions.  Although a specific item may be defective does not discount the thinking behind the type.  For instance; if you are saying A particular military boot is ineffective therefore ALL boots are ineffective then a similar strawman argument can be made about any piece of outdoor equipment or clothing.  My Karrimor Trail Shoes are ineffective therefore ALL trail shoes are ineffective. It's a nonsense straw man argument

Comment: Also that current boot that you linked to is not the current boot; all UK military personnel are issued a choice of Meindl or Lowa desert boots for operations - I have two pairs in my cupboard right now and they served me well in Afghanistan across various terrain types and in various UK training climates.   Also, the link you provided about wearing a packframe while prone...why on earth would you post that?!  Who wears a bergan while prone?!  The packframe becomes a cover item in the prone, or, if under effective fire, the packframe is ditched for a grab-bag and a counter attack.

Answer (score 30):

There seems to be a general trend for people abandoning traditional hiking boots for lighter approach shoes. As I see it there's two driving factors here:

- Approach shoes have gotten better

No need to have a choice between trainers and boots any more. You can get good solid approach shoes that are both light and sturdy enough for use in the outdoors

- People are hiking more and more technical terrain

Scrambling is becoming a bigger and bigger pursuit in the mountains. The lines between hiking and rock climbing are blurring. So, so is the footwear. People want a pair of shoes that they can smear on rock/squeeze into tight jams, etc now. Boots are often just too clunky for this type of mountaineering.

---

For me it's horses for courses and a lot down to personal preference. Providing it's working for the person I don't think I'd insist that they wear x type of boot.

**Winter mountaineering/high altitude** is a little different. You need good insulation and the ability to add crampons, etc. here. So it's just stupid to not wear boots in these circumstances.

---

Personally I have 4 pairs of mountaineering footwear for different occasions. I have

1. Scarpa B2 winter boots and crampons for winter
2. Asolo medium weight (B0) boots for spring/summer/autmn hiking
3. Salewa approach shoes for scrambling, approach to climbs and walking the dogs
4. Red Chilli rock boots for climbing/high grade scrambling on occasion

There's no one boot for all occasions. Different footwear has different advantages and is disadvantages and I don't feel it's correct to criticise x type of boot/shoe. It depends on the circumstances.

Comment: I noticed that yesterday when visiting two outdoor stores (Blacks and Mountain Hardwear), that neither of them sold any shoes I would consider hiking in.  Surprised to see this in the UK, where neither wet terrain nor rocky terrain is in short supply.

Comment: @gerrit did you mean Mountain Warehouse? I've had good stuff from them in the past (including some end-of-line boots that held up well) but I wouldn't rate their stuff overall, or take their stocking policy as advice.  Blacks should be better, perhaps their stock is more seasonal than you'd expect.

Comment: You can get waterproof technical approach shoes. I use a pair of [Salewa Evos](http://www.salewa.com/en/men-firetail-evo-shoes.html) if I'm scrambling. Good grip and goretex lined

Comment: Regardless of waterproofness, if they're 5 cm high they can't keep me dry in the same swamps and streams as when they're 25 cm high (I added a third, more extreme example, that I often see used in Scandinavia).

Comment: If I'm going somewhere wet I wouldn't wear them. It's horse for courses

Comment: This is the best response, in terms of the 'horses for courses' bit. Obviously, if it's -20C outside, then the approach shoes stay in the rack, and the boots go on. Similarly, if it's an all day slog in 8" of snow, then it's boots and gaiters. Talus...I'm still rocking some boots because I've gotten mashed a few times.

Comment: @gerrit: It's true that a low shoe won't keep your feet dry in swamps and streams.  However, if you spend much time in Utah, or indeed much of the western US, you may notice that swamps and streams (at least those too big to jump or use stepping stones) are not exactly major terrain features.  Horses for courses - and riding boots for when I'm riding the horse, of course :-)

Answer (score 23):

> Why do so many people hike with such light footwear?

I can give you a personal perspective: I have hiked in the 2000-3000m altitude (alps) for a long time, using quite tough semi-alpine boots (like the one in your first image, even the same brand).

I still do that today if there is snow or ice, especially since I am also snow-shoeing and using crampons with them. Some light glacier crossings as well.

Recently, I've changed to some extremely light and absolutely non-supporting shoes (Roclite 295). They are not water-tight (water can flow through them) nor airtight (if a cold wind is blowing, you really notice); they are like running shoes for rougher terrain. The point is - it is just a different approach to hiking.

I have to be much more alert all the time, in difficult terrain. I have to look where I step, I can not have my attention all over the place and chat all the time. I absolutely cannot let my body weight just hit the floor wherever it so happens. I consider that a bonus.

This is now the mode of travel that I much prefer. My personal benefits are...

- No trouble with sweat, heat etc.; no buildup of moisture on the inside.
- No trouble with getting wet from the outside. If they come in contact with water, they are instantly soaked through. But afterwards, they become dry equally quickly (while walking). Of course, getting them wet is not advisable in rain or cold weather and they are utterly useless on snow or ice since you cannot "dig in".
- If I wish to, I can move fast, running up- or downhill. This is also possible with the boots, at least downhill, but much less fun for me.
- No problems with blisters, at all.
- The soles are, while being flexible instead of stiff, very sticky in most conditions, that is, they are not slippery at all. No problem to walk over inclined stone surfaces and such. (This is the same for the heavier boots.) More like climbing shoes. Much different than, say, generic sports shoes/sneakers.
- Similar to barefoot running (i.e., Vibram Five Fingers or whatever), I believe my bones/ligaments/ankles/toes/soles will become stronger and more adapted (or at least used) to the load, and I am generally more aware of what I'm doing. My soles give me a lot of feedback about what's happening down there. I step lighter (good for the knees...) and I find that my feet often "auto-correct" a bad step before worse things happen. Of course, hard to tell scientifically, from a personal point of observation.
- Last but not least, I can wear them all day, everywhere, when not hiking. They are a bit colorful and do not go well with a business suit (well, depending on the kind of business - might be OK in a "hip" company). They have actually become my everyday shoes, as they are very, very comfortable for me (mainly due to the breathability).

I admit that I have not researched what the prominent modes of ankle injury actually are for hikers. I would assume that most of those are from people who are not used to hiking/cross-country/climbing.

Comment: Very similar to my own experience. I would only add that for moderate snow and ice (for  example short passages over passes during a long walk) you can use lightweight traction devices. Together with walking poles, I've found them fine:

http://www.vargooutdoors.com/pocket-cleats.html
http://kahtoola.com/product/microspikes/

Comment: Voted up for mentioning that the technique changes depending on the boots. I'll add also that there is an adaptation period. Like you, I believe that my ankles are adapted to the lighter style, but I expect someone suddenly switching from heavy boots to light boots is at greater risk of injury if they don't take it easy initially.

Comment: @Tullochgorum, those cleats look neat. The price, ouch, but I'll keep them in mind. I'd need some heavy duty socks though to use them without freezing. :)

Comment: "I have to be much more alert all the time, in difficult terrain." I'd like to add that I consider this a bonus.  I've hiked in vibram five fingers for a few years and on my last hike I watched 4 people slip on wet rocks - some fell very hard. I walked over the same rocks, just more carefully (which is now second nature), and never once lost my footing.  I find it similar to a blog I read by a very remote off road adventurist who doesn't have a winch on his land rover, the idea being that it would provide a false security and "enable" him to take chances that were more likely to get him stuck

Comment: Yes, I consider that a bonus as well, @plast1k.

Answer (score 15):

The hiking shoe/waterproof trainer style is comfortable for casual strolls on easy trails, *in good weather*.  This "light outdoors" (or fair-weather hiking) market is huge in comparison to serious hiking.  The shoes can be made quite cheaply and don't last all that long.  That's not a big deal - either you take to it and replace them with something better, you buy a new pair quite frequently or you only wear them occasionally and they last.  I normally have 1-2 pairs on the go.

The more heavy-duty market expects something tougher and therefore more expensive.  This won't be an impulse buy in most cases, so the high street shopd won't stock so many (except possibly in the winter).

I personally have a selection - from approach shoes to "soft boots" (synthetic+suede, breathable) to some seriously heavy leather scarpas that have lasted 20 years and will probably do the same again if I'm generous with the nikwax.  The last pair are great if I know I'm going to be wading up to ~8" (2 dm) deep (and really comfy when I'm upright), but they're heavy and too solid around the ankle to drive in.  If I'm going to be in deeper water than that, I'd actually prefer my running shoes that are free draining (or my kayaking gear).

Years ago I had a week's desert walking coming up, and bought some non-waterproof ankle boots (but otherwise very similar to the approach shoes sold now, in quality as well as style).  In the hot conditions they were perfect.

The same logic can be applied to a lot of other outdoor kit - waterproofs, rucksacks etc.

Comment: Having read some other answers again I realise I haven't mentioned people who have made an active, considered choice. The extreme example would be fell runners, some of whom seem to weigh less than the gear I'd have in similar terrain.

Comment: I can't agree that trail shoes are only suitable for "casual strolls ... in good weather". I've used them in apocalyptic rain and alpine snowstorms, though mud and bogs and rock-fields and tussock grass and pretty much every kind of gnarly terrain. It's even possible to handle moderate snowfields with the new lightweight traction devices. I too have a pair of 20 year old Scarpas, but I haven't used them in years. When it gets cold it takes a certain degree of knowledge and judgement, but I've never had any issues. It's not for everyone, but it's  certainly possible.

Comment: @Tullogorum, I didn't mean they're not useful for anything else. I meant they're ideal for a large segment of people. Many of us here will be quite willing to spend money on kit and treat choosing what use on a given day as almost part of the activity. We're a small market compared to the target for e.g. Blacks. Example: There's a route here that if it's been raining I'll run in cross country shoes or walk in big boots, but would only wear approach shoes after a dry spell because they'd fill and not empty.

Answer (score 14):

For certain types of hiking, lightness is key. I can't talk for everyone doing that (some may just be unaware of the consequences of their kit choices) but I really like speed hiking / fell running, and for that I use very lightweight Salomon boots that are almost trainers/sneakers. My wife briefly tried the Vibram Five Fingers and really liked them for hiking.

I'm quite happy with these on a 20 mile a day trek with minimal pack as long as it is reasonably dry and I'm not on actual mountains.

If I'm trekking in the Highlands, across bogland or if the weather is looking to be really wet, proper boots will win, but they are heavy. Much heavier than fell-runners.

Comment: I met a guy along the Everest Base Camp trek, and saw him go all the way to base camp wearing nothing but Five Fingers.  My feet would have turned to sausage by the end of the first day; he pointed out that he had to work up (long before he went to Nepal) to the point where they felt so good on a trail.

Answer (score 6):

There is a major advantage to lighter footwear when hiking. Here is a great example: [Does a pound on your foot equal 5 pounds on your back?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10846/does-a-pound-on-your-foot-equal-5-pounds-on-your-back)

Newer, light weight footwear can be targeted for hiking more then just a regular cross training or basketball shoe. A good example is the [Moab](http://www.merrell.com/US/en/moab-ventilator-wide-width/018469008796.html?CID=MAR-Merrell-G-Shopping-Moab-Ventilator-Wide-Width&CAWELAID=120144300000097308&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=21158942165&CATCI=pla-169179303365). Much more hardcore hikers than I use Merrell's on the PCT, JMT, etc.

Heavy hiking boots aren't usually needed unless in very rocky terrain, imo. It is all based on the person and situation (ex: easy rescue?).

Answer (score 5):

For a long time, there was a trend towards heavier shoes with more support.  The logic was that it provided protection for your joints, and your anecdotal evidence suggests that it works.

Bear with me for a moment, and permit me to take the argument to an unreasonable extreme.  Encase you entire foot in a solid steel block, well up into the calf.  Now you can prove without a question that you're protecting your ankle.

Obviously that extreme example is unrealistic, but it does demonstrate that the "best" answer has to be a balancing act.  Clearly there are advantages to support, and disadvantages to support.  Otherwise we would all be either barefoot or wearing steel boots.

One of the issues with the heavy boots I have identified is that they encourage dependence on them.  There is a set of skills your body needs to practice to keep itself stable without relying on ankle support.  If you always have heavy boots on, that skill (and its associated muscles) atrophies.  As you mentioned, you found it horrible to try to go even a short distance with lightweight shoes.  On the other hand, if you have light shoes, you are *obliged* to maintain stability, and will damage your body if you don't.  If you're the kind of person that likes to get distracted and let their body do all the walking, you'll likely put yourself in a bad position with a high likelihood of ankle damage.

Another issue is shock.  If you have intentionally restricted motion of the ankle joint, you lose the ability to cushion blows using those tendons.  The force is naturally taken up by the ankles and hips.  Do you naturally walk on your heels?  Then you probably will find that that ankle restriction really doesn't impact you all that much.  If you naturally walk closer to the balls of your feet, losing that mobility has a much larger impact.

In the end, the best answer is to do what is comfortable for you, but don't be afraid to explore outside of the box a bit.  Your definition of comfortable may move.  Personally, I like hiking with lightweight shoes.  However, if you look at the military, who have to make tremendous slogs with heavy packs without twisting an ankle, they're all in high-support shoes for good reason.  I don't think we'll see our armed forces deploying in Vibram toe shoes any time soon!

Comment: You can easily find boots with total ankle support: downhill ski boots.  Awkward to walk in, and look at the rate of broken legs & knee injuries.

Comment: I recently had to see a physio. He had seen two new clients with broken ankles that week. And they had both been wearing ski boots. High boots  can protect you somewhat from turning an ankle, but they can't protect you from torque injuries.

Answer (score 4):

For me with my almost 130kg (280 lbs) weight the best choice turned out to go "barefoot" ... Five years ago, I walked with my friend across entire Poland (over 850 km) in a month and after the first week my feet were wasted.  Had to take a two day break, treat all the bruises and calluses which were caused by the heavier trekking shoes.  Some might say as above that they were not fitted well.  They were - they were well broken in from all the winter trekking in the mountains, but totally unsuited for hot summer weather.  If you are keeping the shoes on your feet for 8-10 hours day after day, no magical membrane etc. will help you to get rid of all that perspiration which leaves through your feet.  Fortunatelly I also had a pair of lightweight mesh shoes and finished the rest of our trip wearing those.

Since then I have been a big fan of the mininalist/barefoot approach which came to me intuitivelly.  Then a year or so ago I have read a book "Born to run" about ultramarathons and the Tarahumara tribe etc.  It turns out that those guys in their "sandals" (sometimes even just a piece of rubber tire just to protect the sole of their feet) often outperform sportsman with the newest high-tech gear.  My preffered shoes nowadays are Inov-8 bare-grip 200 for summer hiking and for winter salomon speedcross 3 Gtx with a pair of well fitted snow gaiters.  The bare grip have excellent holding tread whilst a very thin sole, so that you can and will (you will need a while to get used to it and sometimes at first it can be fainfull if you step on protruding rocks etc.) get an excellent feel the surface, plus the shoe is really soft and will not constrain all those bones in your feet, which were "designed" by evolution to ideally absorb all the shock, vibration etc. which you are subjecting your body to when walking.

Because it's not only about your feet - wear a pair of "bouncy-sole" shoes and it might feel really comfortable on your feet, but then you might be subjecting your knees to much higher shock when the forces of the bounce add up to your body falling down.  here's a good article here explaining better the idea than I did ... [The painful truth about trainers: Are running shoes a waste of money?](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/moslive/article-1170253/The-painful-truth-trainers-Are-expensive-running-shoes-waste-money.html) Ps. Our fanpage about our last trip and the upcomming one this summer ... Poland again, this time West to East ... [Podróże po Polsce](https://www.facebook.com/zpoludnianapolnoc/).

Answer (score 4):

To a large extent, it depends on the climate, terrain, and trail conditions of the part of the US that you are hiking in; your observations are limited to one section of the US.

Also, prior answers have not mentioned the advantage of a stiffer sole with a shank for rock and root hopping.

Compared to the Eastern or Midwestern sections of the US, the western US (which contains the PCT and the CDT) has a much drier climate, fewer rivers, less mud, more dust, fewer rocks and roots, and smoother and better graded trails.

Early conventional wisdom was to use heavier boots.  This was because:

- Many of the early writers hiked on East coast
- Eastern trails were constructed earlier, mostly as foot trails, and tend to go straight up and down the slopes to minimize erosion. This puts a premium on traction, wetness prevention, and foot protection.

In the 80s and 90s, Ray Jardine popularized using sneakers on the PCT, which is very smooth and dry.

However, hikers in the Adirondacks have to deal with rain nearly every day, deep mud, large numbers of rock crossings, and poorly maintained trails; a much larger proportion of them choose ankle-high boots.  Most streams have bridges there, so one doesn't have to swap footwear very often.

Finally, Scandanavia features a lot of bogs and swamps and is generally quite wet; relatively few streams have bridges.  Knee-high rubber Wellington-style boots allow you to walk cross-country through mud and streams without changing footwear.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't meant for general advice but for hiking, backpacking, and snowshoeing I prefer light, really light -- I use my running shoes...much lighter than what you have pictured as *light*.

I'm reasonably fit and active -- I'm a former competitive endurance athlete. My running shoes provide adequate support for me and I'm much more agile in them than my *hiking boots*...and my snowshoeing is generally high intensity so dryness and warmth is no problem (they get soaked but my feet are **hot**) in the low-humidity high mountains of Utah, USA.

Answer (score 3):

I continue to use Gortex lined boots because I hate wet feet. I use a light boot with serious socks for comfort and dryness.

Last hike on the AT in the Smokies, all the serious through-hikers were using very lightweight shoes or boots. Discussing it with them, they focused on:

1. Speed over support because they are typically young and healthy
2. Dryness in hot weather. Running shoes provide more ventilation.
3. Comfort over very long distances. Boots tend to have pressure points.

Answer (score 3):

As you've noted, the purpose of heavy boots is to reduce the likelihood and severity of foot and ankle injuries.  I would argue that lighter equipment in general also accomplishes the same thing, reducing the need for heavy boots.  You're less likely to place your foot badly, and less likely to be injured if you do, if you're not carrying 100 pounds of gear on your back.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to consider is the height of the heel. I personally think it is actually much easier to roll your ankle whilst wearing the 'proper hike boots' with the higher heels (and I have unfortunately done so quite often especially when carrying a heavy pack) than it is with the (usually) lower heel of the 'lightweight sports shoes'. The amount of ankle support the 'hike boots' give you can be easily measured for yourself. Put them on and lace them up then deliberately stand on the outside edge of the boot and try to start to roll your ankle. I've tried this with a number of these styles of boot and they didn't give much if any support, even when laced up tightly. They will NOT stop you rolling your ankle. I find the lower shoes do not roll so easily and when they do (and they will) it doesn't hurt so much.

Answer (score 3):

Twenty years ago I hiked the Bandiagara Falaise in a pair of trail running shoes. A couple in our party actually wore Tevas. The choice wasn't made out of fashion or ignorance (6 year 82nd Airborne veteran here) but out of what would work best in 121°F (49°C) heat traversing steep canyon hikes and with in the same day long stretches of walking on sandy flats.

When I was in the service the most popular boot was the Jungle Boot:

[image: Jungle Boot]

[Jungle boot](http://www.askahain.de/vietnam/vn-database-mirror/USarmy/Jungleboots.jpg)

They were a cloth upper with leather lowers. People loved them because they were light and breathable and as you can see from the image, there wasn't a whole lot of ankle support.

Answer (score 1):

The ankle support of hiking boots is a myth.  Being heavy and more cumbersome, you are more like to turn an ankle wearing them across some rocky paths than being more nimble in a trail runner or hiking shoe.  If your ankles are weak, you should do exercises to strengthen them.  Wearing an ankle brace with trail runners would be better than wearing the big boots.  Much lighter and far more ankle support.  Wearing heavy boots makes a person tired and a tired hiker is one more prone to missteps. And if it's really raining, I don't care what shoes you have, you will get wet. Trail runners with mesh will dry far quicker than boots with leather or nubuck.  It can take days for leather/nubuck boots to dry.

Comment: My feet hurt when I hike for more than a couple of hours in £100 "trail shoes" (which I find indistinguishable from sport shoes), they don't hurt in £200 hiking boots until after 10+ hours of hiking.  And from personal experience on steep downhill friction walking, I strongly disagree with your allegation that ankle support is a myth.  It feels completely unstable on slopes.  I've learned from the answers that even experienced people choose to use them, but I cannot possibly reconcile that with the personal experience of myself or anyone I've ever hiked with.

Comment: http://www.cleverhiker.com/blog/ditch-boots

Comment: http://www.fjaderlatt.se/2009/05/interview-chris-townsend-on-footwear.html

Comment: Having walked thousands of miles in Europe, I have found that a great majority of the time, hiking shoes or trail runners are more than sufficient.  I am very fit and maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: My experience is different, although I rarely hike more than 40 km/day, whether it's tarmac, trailless swamps, steep gravel, it feels **much** better in [Hanwag Tatra](http://www.hanwag.com/tatra-top-wide-gtxr) than in [Meindl GTX](http://www.meindl.de/deutsch/modelle/schuh_detail2.asp?ID=2173).  I appreciate boots like the Hanwag Tatra may be overkill on European long-distance trails like Jakobsweg or Pieterpad, for me it certainly isn't in the Alps or Sarek.  I've seen experienced hikers such as Townsend deny such boots are needed, and perhaps they aren't for him, but they are for me.

Comment: The question has been answered already; some people do have arguments for such footwear.  I disagree.  Fortunately, outdoor stores still sell both, so each person can wear what they prefer.

Comment: I will be on the Jakobsweg next week.  Plan on wearing either Inov-8 X Claw or Merrell FST.  Merrill is a bit heavy but may give it a go